# Call telerik function which sort columns in grid

Tags: jquery, grid, telerik

I have a telerik grid

```
@Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("OrdersGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
        columns.Bound(o => o.RequiredDate);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .ColumnContextMenu()
```

))

and it is standart function right mouse click on grid header and choose column 
how can I do this function on click by some other element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide some more specific information but would this help you?

```
$("#SomeOtherElementID").click(function() {

    ColumnContextMenu();
    //$("tr:first").focus(); 

});
```

Comment: instead of Run the default function $("tr:first").focus(); 
I need call telerik function which do sort of columns on grid

Comment: this function is in telerik.grid.min is any way to call this function on click by some other element?

Comment: Isn't telegrig table still HTML table in DOM with many extra stuff in it? My jQuery should focus it eventough it is telegrid because the html still has tr. But yes you can. Can you tell me the id/class/something of the element on click you want to do stuff and then the function you want to call?

Comment: this function name is ColumnContextMenu() I need to call this

Comment: like this http://jsbin.com/ihivif/265/edit but it for Kendo I need Telerik because that function call right mouse button

Comment: ColumnContextMenu() is undefined

Comment: I need to call telerik function ColumnContextMenu() from js